# Can the list margin be increased?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I reformatted the list in this question [*Developing the news area for a website*](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12950/developing-the-news-area-for-a-website), with the aim of making the list a little easier to read (i.e. more obvious that it's a list). Upon completion of that formatting I see that I haven't really achieved a lot:

[image]

Can the left margin of the list be made 1 or 2 ems bigger, just to indent it a little more? It may not look so bad in the picture I've supplied, but the margin is not so obvious when you have the whole page up in front of you.

Comment: Actually, the margin looks pretty clear to me both on the screen capture and on the full page.

Comment: Not for me, but that might be because I have fonts notched up a scale and the left-margin is expressed in px and not em. It should be in ems so the indent is relative to font size. 3em works for me, 4em seems generous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have increased the margin some to accommodate for larger font size. The change will be in the next production build.